# Proper way to use Select tags with POST in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post, submit

I'm building a rails app right now where a user will select a date with the form below and press the Submit button.

Three questions:
1) What is the correct way to get this to post to my DB? 
2) Does my submit button need to be inside of my form tag?
3) How do I generate a scaffold to take these fields correctly?

Thanks in advance for the help. I really do appreciate this wonderful community and look forward to giving back one day when I'm more adept.

```
<div id="dateFields">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<select name="lunchMonth">
    <option>Month</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="lunchDay">
    <option>Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="lunchYear">
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
</form>
</div> <!-- End DateField -->

<br /><br />
<a class="whiteButton" href="#confirmed" type="submit" value="send">Confirm</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While starting with an existing blob of HTML and then trying to build an RoR controller/model to receive information from the form is certainly possible... it's a bit unusual. Typically, one would also use RoR views/form helpers to render the HTML, which clearly was not done in this case.

It's hard to answer your question, as posed, because you are starting from a slightly odd place.  I think all would become clearer to you if wrote a few example forms/controllers/models using RoR scaffolds for all parts of the MVC framework.  Maybe start with [Rails for Zombies](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies)?

Answer (score 0):

I think [#213 Calendars](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars) episode from railscasts will help you to understand the date picker and make it in proper way.